# Spring Batch: How to configure PagingQueryProvider without a SortKeys

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm trying to configure a JdbcPagingItemReader bean and I don't know exactly the names of the columns in the table so I'd like to know if there is a way to configure a PagingQueryProvider without a sort key.

```
@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<Map<String, Object>> pagingItemReader(DataSource dataSource){
    JdbcPagingItemReader<Map<String, Object>> itemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider());
    itemReader.setPageSize(1000);

    itemReader.setRowMapper(BatchConfiguration::rowMapper);

    return itemReader;
}


/* This configuration throws the exception
 * 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sortKey must be specified'
 */
private MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider(){
    MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
    queryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT *");
    queryProvider.setFromClause("FROM "+ clientTableName);

    return queryProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know if there is a way to configure a PagingQueryProvider without a sort key.

No, this is not possible. The `sortKey` is mandatory to build the SQL statement. Here is an excerpt from the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#JdbcPagingItemReader):

> The SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean requires that you specify a select clause and a from clause. You can also provide an optional where clause. These clauses and **the required sortKey** are used to build an SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mahmoud for answering my question, I am dealing with a situation with an unknown sql table structure so I can't provide a column name to the setter and it hasn't accepted a number for the column position. Have you any idea how I can solve this problem?